# Interacting with IE tabs once opened

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

What I'm trying to do here is automate the opening of several helpdesk tickets simultaneously in separate IE tabs.  I create a list of ticket numbers in Excel and then loop through the ticket numbers, opening each one.

My code seems to work fine when I open each one in a separate IE instance, but since I've tried to open them in separate tabs of one IE instance, I get an error on the second loop.  Here is what I have so far:

```vb
Set Tickets = Sheet5.Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown))

Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
ie.Visible = 1
apiShowWindow ie.hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE

For Each Ticket In Tickets

If Ticket <> "" And Not Ticket Like "IM*" And Not Ticket Like "ARS*" And Not      Ticket Like "C*" Then

    'Load Mantis Page
    If Tabbed = False Then
        ie.Navigate "http://URL"
    Else:
        ie.Navigate "http://URL", CLng(2048)
    End If

    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 4

    'LoginCheck
    Set LoginExists = ie.document.getElementById("username")
    If LoginExists Is Nothing Then
        GoTo SearchForTicket
    Else: GoTo Login
    End If

Login:
    Call ie.document.getElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "xx")
    Call ie.document.getElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", "xx")
    ie.document.getElementById("login_form").Submit

    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until ie.ReadyState = 3
    GoTo SearchForTicket

    'Search for Mantis ticket
SearchForTicket:

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    ie.document.All("bug_id").Value = Ticket

    Set AllButtons = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each Button In AllButtons
            If Button.Value = "Jump" Then
                Button.Click
                Exit For
            End If

        Next
End If
Tabbed = True
Next
```

It works the first time around, and opens IE, navigates to the page and searches for the ticket.  The second time around, it opens the new tab and navigates to the page, but when it tries to search for the second ticket, I get an error saying:

```vb
Object doesn't support this property or method"
```

On line:

```vb
ie.document.All("bug_id").Value = Ticket
```

I've been searching for an answer with no luck so far.  Any help would be appreciated.